# How to make MediaWiki search work better?

Tags: mediawiki

The basic search capabilities of MediaWiki (at least, the version we're running - 1.7.1) are pretty poor. I'd like to improve them with an extension, but there are a lot of options and I'd like to have a good starting point.

For what it's worth, the wiki is an internal one; we don't have the option, for example, of using the Google search extension, because it's not going to be able to crawl the wiki's contents. I need a solution that will run entirely on the wiki server.

Here are the wiki version details:

```
MediaWiki: 1.7.1
PHP: 5.2.8 (apache2handler)
MySQL: 4.1.21-log
```

What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're using the [SphinxSearch](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SphinxSearch) extension and it is *much* better than the default Mediawiki search.  The extension installs directly in the Mediawiki server.  SphinxSearch is only "supported" on Mediawiki 1.9+, but you may be able to shoe-horn it for testing purposes.

Aside: I would recommend you look into upgrading your Mediawiki install as well as Apache, PHP and MySQL.  All versions you list (save for Apache) are out-of-date and have one or more exploits publicly available.  I understand this is an internal wiki, but that affords you greater options for testing without interruption in service.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to do these things:

1. Upgrade your MediaWiki version. This will enable you to
2. Install [Lucene search](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lucene-search). Installation is not always easy but when it is working it works well and this is the standard search used on most "official" MediaWiki sites, e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Version). (Strictly speaking, you can install Lucene without upgrading, but see the notes on the link.)
3. Have you switched on [search suggest](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgEnableMWSuggest) (for MediaWiki versions < 1.20.0)?

Answer (score 3):

These days you should look at [CirrusSearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CirrusSearch). It's an ElasticSearch-powered search extension, Wikipedia is in the process of switching to it.